# Php String union and intersection

Tags: php, string

I am stuck at this problem. 
I have an array like :

Array ( [0] => usb [1] => usb pc [2] => pc [3] => camera [4] => camera 168 [5] => 168 )

I want to output only two entries from the above array which contains [usb pc] and [camera 168]
because their disintegration already have other elements so no need of those elements.

another example

[kaushik]
[kaushik is]
[kaushik is great]
[is]
[is great]
[great]

This should out put only [kaushik is great]  element.

another example :

[usb]
[pc]
[cam 168]
[cam]
[168]

This should out put [usb] [pc] and [cam 168] elements.

The above problem is a part of one problem in which i want to find out the number of split points in a string.

For example string is : USB PC CAMERA DOWNLOAD 168

keyword : USB PC CAMERA 168

here in the string the keyword is split by the word DOWNLOAD if you can guess.

So number of splits = 1

again if we take string: USB of our PC the CAMERA DOWNLOAD 168

here the keyword is split by "of our" "the" and "DOWNLOAD"

hence number of splits = 3

Comment: How exactly does your array look like? Can you post a `print_r()` output of your array? (Output them in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags for a more readable output)

Comment: Array ( [0] => usb [1] => usb pc [2] => pc [3] => camera )

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22730127/edit) your question to add this information.

Comment: why [usb] and [pc] were in output of last sample? their disintegration has what?

Comment: since they are alone and are not contained in any other element they should be output. if there was one more entry like [usb xyz] then [usb] should have not been output

Comment: It's important that you realize of the time complexity of this problem and how its processing time grows with each added element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't thoroughly tested this but i think it works fine.

```
<?php

    // just comment/uncomment to choose which $data you want to see in action

   //$data = array("kaushik","kaushik is","kaushik is great","is","is great","great");
   $data = array("usb","pc","cam 168","cam","168");

    $current = "";

    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $current=$data[$i];

        for($j=0;$j<count($data);$j++)
        {
            if($i<>$j)
            {
                if((str_replace($data[$j],"",$current))!=$current)
                {
                    $data[$j]="";
                };
            }
        }
    }

    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        if($data[$i]!="")
        {
            echo $data[$i]."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

results are

```
kaushik is great
```

and for the other data set:

```
usb 
pc
cam 168
```

in action here: http://3v4l.org/9XUPJ

Comment: since i see you are a new user, remember you can vote/accept this answer if you think it solve your problem

Comment: Works fine but before choosing as answer i will test is well

Answer (score 1):

Have tested it, and it seems to work fine. (**Fixed bug with dupes**)

```
    <?php
// $a = array( 'kaushik', 'kaushik is', 'kaushik is great', 'is', 'is great', 'great' );
$a = array('usb', 'pc', 'cam 168', 'cam', '168', 'cam 168');

$a = array_unique($a);
$s = count($a);
$p = array();

foreach ($a as $key => $b)
{
    $x = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $s; $i++)
    {
        if ($key == $i) continue;

        $c = $a; unset($c[$key]);
        if (strpos($c[$i], $b) === false) $x++;

        if ($x == $s - 1) array_push($p, $key);
    }
}

foreach ($p as $o => $value) {
    echo $a[$value]. ' ';
}
?>
```

In action [**here**](http://3v4l.org/Jp2nn)